# Is it possible to find a memory leak using firebase performance?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-performance

ReactNative: 0.61.4

I am getting memory leak in my React Native app.
I found out what page it is, but I haven't found what the cause is.
In this situation, can use Firebase Performance Monitoring to find the cause of a memory leak?

```
this.trace = perf().newTrace('page1');
await this.trace.start();
```

Firebase Performance Monitoring is inserted in this way.

However, when I use it in this way, I can see that the memory increases over time, but I can't find the cause.

In this case, which function of Firebase Performance Monitoring is suitable?

Is it a bad tool for finding memory leaks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Performance Monitoring is not designed to detect memory leaks.  It's designed to measure the performance (speed) of code and HTTP requests.